# Count Blank Cells Until Value is Found

Tags: excel, excel-formula, excel-2010, excel-2016, excel-2019

How can I find a count of blank cells until a value is found in a row?
I did some searching and found that I could use either
`COUNTBLANK with INDIRECT` or `COUNTIF` or `MATCH with INDEX`

But couldn't get it to work on any of them...

The formula should go into B5.
Example:

[image]

Thank you for the help.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use MATCH() Function:

```
=MATCH(FALSE,ISBLANK(B1:F1),0)-1
```

That formula will give you the number of cells to the first non-blank cell, so if you substract one you’ll get the number of blank cells. As is an array formula confirm it with CRTL+SHIFT+ENTER instead of ENTER so you get the brackets {} in the formula:

```
{=MATCH(FALSE,ISBLANK(B1:F1),0)-1}
```

Comment: I'm trying to understand the formula but either way I get an error #N/A.
So I changed it to something like `=MATCH(FALSE,INDEX(B1:F1="",),0)-1`

Comment: The formula that @Kaiser has suggested needs to be confirmed with CONTROL+SHIFT+ENTER, not just ENTER.

Comment: Thanks Domenic for claryifing, I’ve updated the answer.

Comment: I believe my formula is better because it doesn't use array... but thanks!

Comment: Rather an array than a volatile function

Answer (score 0):

Please try this basic Lookup function. (This is normal function which means no need to confirm CTRL+Shift+Enter.)

> This below function needs to be written on A1 then you can drag it down.

```
=LOOKUP(2,1/($A1:G1<>""),COLUMN($A1:G1))-2
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use a combination of `MATCH` and `MAX` (or `MIN`) for this:

[image]

Formula in `B5`:

```
=MATCH(MAX(B1:G1),B1:G1,0)-1
```

Drag down

Comment: Then specify your questions better. It works on what you told us.